# How to rename parent tags in Firestore json documents?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I have a requirement to understand the different tags coming in my Firestore json documents. The tags are named like: d1,d2,d3 etc. and have some values like 'Automatic', 'Brand', 'Manual' etc. I want to be able to rename these keys (d1, d2, d3) to better ones like 'Brand Name', 'Category' etc. depending on the values these keys are holding across all my documents within my collection. How can I identify what each key (parent tag) is indicating in Firestore documents? Can this be achieved through index creation?

Answer (score 3):

So my understanding is that wou want to count what are the most frequent values for a given field in a document collection. You cant just do that using a query like you would in SQL, there is not count functions in Firestore.

I see two options:

1. You pull all the documents and you count them. Obviously if you do that several times it will be very expensive in reads
2. You increment a counter at document creation and you sort on this counter afterwards. The way you structure the counters is up to your requirements:

   a) They could be all in one document

   b) or you could have a counter collection and 1 document per field (d1, d2, d3)

   c) or you could have one collection per field and then one counter per value (most scalable).

   d) ...

EDIT: a bit more details on option 2

- Counter creation: every time a document is created you increment the counters. For instance: for option 2.b and a new document = {d1: "Automatic, d2: "Brand } you could increment the counters like this

  ```
  colref.doc("d1").set({Automatic: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.increment(1), { merge: true }
  colref.doc("d2").set({Brand: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.increment(1), { merge: true }
  ```

And in general:

```
    colref.doc(field).set({[fieldvalue]: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.increment(1), { merge: true }
```

- Query: for 2.a and 2.b you will need to pull the docs and sort it yourself, for 2.c you could use the console for each field

Comment: Can you please guide me on how can I go about the counter creation in Firestore? Also, from where can I query the Firestore documents? Is it from the Firebase console itself? I am also trying to understand what role would index creation play? Are indexes created just to aid query performance (like in traditional RDS systems)? @Oliver could you please clear my doubts?

Comment: I added some clarifications

Comment: The 2.b approach requires us to know the values of d1, d2 etc... before hand correct? -@Oliver

Comment: No it doesn't. Look at my example "in general"